# iOS: How to switch from one UIViewController to another, including in SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I have an example of `SWRevealViewController` from github. 
And now I'm tryng to understand, how switch my independent `UIViewController` to another, which is including in `SWRevealViewController`.
I read somewhere that this should work:

```
- (IBAction)action:(UIButton *)sender {
      SWRevealViewController *swcontroller = self.revealViewController;
      if (swcontroller) {
         self.revealViewController.frontViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
      }
}
```

and I create a modal segue from my `UIButton` to `SWRevealViewController`.
But it does not work.
Can anybody give an example?

Comment: the above code doesnt present/switch uiviewcontroller.it simply allocates a memory to it

Comment: what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I have a Slide-out Sidebar Menu with one cell, created using SWRevealViewController. By clicking on this cell, opens my ViewController1.  And I have another ViewController2 with UIButton(This controller is not connected with SWRevealViewController). I want to switch my ViewController2 to ViewController1(and having access to my slide-menu), by pressing the button.

Answer (score 4):

As per my information you need to manually push or pop your view controller in SWRevealViewController.As shown below try this..

```
- (IBAction)btnActionSalesQuotation:(id)sender{
SWRevealViewController *revealview = self.revealViewController;

SalesQuotationsViewController *Gosalequo=[[SalesQuotationsViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SalesQuotationsViewController" bundle:nil];

[revealview pushFrontViewController:Gosalequo animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Good idea. Thanks. I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

That code helped me:

```
- (IBAction)act:(UIButton *)sender {
    SWRevealViewController *sw = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SWRevealViewController"];
    UINavigationController *nav = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigationController"];
    [sw setRearViewController:nav];
    sw.frontViewController = nav;
    [self presentViewController:sw animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

I forgot to add *setRearViewController*